# Limit Question: $\lim _{x\to 0^-}\left(1-e^x\right)^{\sin x}$

Tags: limits

I'm new. Sorry for any confusion :)

This is my question:

$$\lim _{x\to 0^-}\left(1-e^x\right)^{\sin x}$$

I've been trying to figure out what to do but I have no idea. I've tried L'Hôpital's rule to get rid of 0/0 equation but it didn't work. I'd really appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: can you edit the post adding what you've tried? Otherwise, the question will be closed

Comment: Do you know Taylor series?

Comment: I've no idea what is it?

Comment: It's the most powerful tool to compute limits. Anyway, if you don't know Taylor series consider rewriting the limit as $e^{\log (1-e^x)^{\sin x}}$

Comment: OK I'm gonna try that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1197666/1118406) question

Comment: @SineoftheTime I am wondering is there is a solution without tylor series or l'hopital rule

Comment: @pie sure, you basically have to compute $\lim_{x\to 0^-} \sin x \log (1-e^x)=\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\sin x}{x}x \log \left(\frac{e^x-1}{x}x\right)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}x \log x$. take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1197666/1118406)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have to evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0^-}(1-e^x)^{\sin x}$
It is in $0^0$ form . So we will take everything in power of e then we will apply LH rule
$$=e^{\lim_{x\to 0^-}\ln(1-e^x)^{\sin x }}$$
$$=e^{\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{\ln(1-e^x)}{\frac{1}{\sin x}}}$$
$$=e^{\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{\frac{1}{1-e^x}\times (-e^{-x})}{-\frac{1}{\sin^2 x}\times\cos x}}$$
$$=e^{\lim_{x\to 0^-}\sin^2 x \times e^{-x}\times \frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}\times \frac{1}{\cos x}}$$
$$=e^{\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}}\times{ \frac{x}{1-e^{x}}\times x}$$
$$=e^0$$
$$=1$$
Hence the limiting value is 1

Comment: How could you write this? The $sinx$ is the exponent. Though there is no a common base, you wrote it as following, $$={\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{\ln(1-e^x)}{\frac{1}{\sin x}}}$$ how?

Comment: @SonerfromTheOttomanEmpire $\log a^b=b\log a=\frac{\log a}{\frac{1}{b}}$

Comment: Thank you. I just felt a trifle ambiguity btw $$={\ln((1-e^x)^{\sin x })}$$ vs 
$$={(\ln(1-e^x))^{\sin x }}$$